# How to use composer for server based and front end components

Tags: composer-php

How do I use composer to manage components in different locations?

I'm currently using composer for server-side components (such as HtmlPurifier and PHPMailer) outside of document root, but I want to use it for the front end components which are located within document root (such as zxcvbnm).

Can I use multiple instances and does this work with PHPStorm (2019)?

Comment: Can you be more specific, e.g. show how both backend & frontend config would differ? Do you mean JS-libraries with frontend component or is this a PHP backend? If this is just about having 2 different `composer.json` files in your project, it is doable (but might lead to conflicts) using the `COMPOSER` environment variable: https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#composer

Comment: @dbrumann I refined the question to add a few examples.